# Debian: Tunnel incoming connections (SSH)

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

Is it possible to use a SSH connection to tunnel incoming traffic to server1 to server2, so server1 acts like a proxy?
Or is there a better way to do it? Cross-server connection should be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do add this to ~/.ssh/config on the source machine.

```
Host host-name
Hostname host-name-or-ip
LocalForward 5900 destination:5900
```

Then

```
ssh -v host-name
```

Now when you connect to port 5900 on the source machine you are 
connected to 5900 on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use -L or -R params from command line.